# ValidationSummary not updating on messagestore.add

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I checked the login remote by a api and adding the validation-errors to `ValidationMessageStore`, but they don't appers in `ValidationSummary`. I want to use the same process in another complex szenarios, where i change migrate the frontend.

If i change the input and a "normal" error comes up, like a required-message appear, all errors appear in the summary. The required-Error and my credential errors. I think the only problem is: that the validation summary don't checked, that there is a new error Message inside. But i don' t know, how i can poke the `ValidationSummary`.

Here is the LogIn.razor.

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="ExecuteLogin" class="card card-body bg-light mt-5" EditContext="editContext">
    <p>DataAnnotationsValidator</p>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <p>ValidationSummary</p>
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText id="email" class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Email" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Email)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText type="password" id="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="model.Password" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Password)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

And here the Login.razor.cs

```
  public partial class LogIn
    {

        private EditContext? editContext;
        private ValidationMessageStore? _messageStore;

        private AuthenticationUserRequest model = new();

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            editContext = new(model);
            editContext.OnValidationRequested += OnValidationRequested;
            _messageStore = new(editContext);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            editContext.OnValidationRequested -= OnValidationRequested;
        }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var state = await _stateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            if (state.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
            }
        }


        private void OnValidationRequested(object? sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            _messageStore?.Clear();
        }


        private async Task ExecuteLogin()
        {

            var result = await _authenticationManager.Login(model);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Notify User and navigate to home
            }
            else
            {
                
                foreach (var message in result.Messages)
                {
                    if (message == "Invalid Credentials.")
                    {
                        _messageStore.Add(() => model.Email, "Invalid Credentials");
                        _messageStore.Add(() => model.Password, "Invalid Credentials");
                        _messageStore.Add(() => model.Password, "Another Error for testing");
                        StateHasChanged();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Notify User
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your code a little to create a single component.  You see the code below.

To answer your question "adding the validation-errors to ValidationMessageStore, but they don't appers in ValidationSummary".

THEY  DON'T, because of the slightly different behaviour of the `ValidationSummary` and `ValidationMessage`.

These are the important changes to make things happen:

1. I've removed your `ValidationStateChanged` registration as I don't think you need it.
2. I've added clearing the message storebvto `ExecuteLogIn` before adding the custom messages
3. Called `editContext!.NotifyValidationStateChanged();` after adding the messages.

Step 3 is the important bit for `ValidationSummary`.  As `ExecuteLogIn` yields, `EditContext` get thread time to run the `OnValidationStateChanged` registered event handlers. `ValidationSummary` is one of these.  It reads the "empty" validation store and re-renders long before you have added the custom messages.  Nothing has changed for `ValidationSummary` when you finally re-render your main page, so no final re-render.  Calling `NotifyValidationStateChanged` triggers that re-render.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow.Server.Pages
{
    public partial class LogIn
    {
        private EditContext? editContext;
        private ValidationMessageStore? _messageStore;

        private AuthenticationUserRequest model = new();

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            editContext = new(model);
            _messageStore = new(editContext);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task ExecuteLogin()
        {
            var result =  await this.ValidateLogin();
            if (result)
            {
                // Notify User and navigate to home
            }
            else
            {
                _messageStore?.Clear();
                _messageStore!.Add(() => model.Email, "Invalid Email");
                _messageStore!.Add(() => model.Password, "Invalid Password");
                _messageStore!.Add(() => model.Message, "Invalid Credentials");
                editContext!.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
                await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> ValidateLogin()
        {
             await Task.Delay(1000);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class AuthenticationUserRequest
    {
        public string Email { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

}
```